# Disable Confirm Button conditionally in sweetalert

Tags: angular, sweetalert

In one of my code I am using javascript sweet alert library:

https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2

I want to disable Confirm Button conditionally, but not able to find such property in documentation yet.

Have anyone used this?

PS: In documentation I found `swal.disableConfirmButton()` method but while using the same Angular throws an error

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_sweetalert2___default.a.disableConfirmButton is not a function
```

Comment: How are you importing `swal` in your class?

Comment: Configuration for `swal` is working fine, Just issue with at the time of button `disabled` else everything working like charm

Comment: Can you show the entire code how you disable it?

Comment: I am just added `swal.disableConfirmButton();` this piece of code for disable functionality

Comment: I would recommend to use ngx-sweetalert2 with is for angular only . https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2 . Which version are you using?

Comment: @PardeepJain it does exist in the code https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/src/instanceMethods/enable-disable-elements.js#L20

Comment: Can you post your html code? You are using which version of angular ?

Comment: @Niladri V4 I am using, Yes code does exist as I already stated in question. But I am not able to find out the way of using this method

Comment: @PardeepJain use the ngx-version .. it's an instance method you can call it on the exported class `SweetAlert`

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue where I was importing 'sweetalert2' as :

`import swal2 from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js' 
 import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css'`.

Adding following code worked for me.

```
 confirmButtonText: 'Submit Bond',
 showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
 onOpen: function (){
              swal2.disableConfirmButton();
                   },
```

Also check on https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/226  :)

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, will check btw thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your explanation well, you are using Angular, you can assign a variable and change it according to your constraints or cases.

For example,

```
disableButton: boolean;
.
.
.
constructor(){
this.disableButton = false;
}
updateDisableButton(){
  if(/*case1**/)
    this.disableButton = true;
  else if
  ...
}
```

in your html

```
<button [disabled]="disableButton"></button>
```

Comment: Have you checked my question? I am asking by using sweetalert package.Please re-read my question

Answer (score 0):

In Swal2 you can use `swal.getConfirmButton()` function to get the button element. Then you can do whatever you want with it. For example, if you use JQuery, you can do something like `$(swal.getConfirmButton()).prop('disabled', true)` easily.
You can refer many useful functions [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#methods) in the documentation.